# Ubuntu: Suddenly i find one of my hard disk partition (/dev/sda5) being displayed as 'Unknown drive'

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Suddenly i find one of my hard disk partition (/dev/sda5) being displayed as 'Unknown drive'. Im unable to mount / retrieve the data on this drive.Im uable edit the partition either. How do i retrieve / store the drive?

I executed the following

```
demo@demo-laptop:~$ sudo fsck -c /dev/sda5
fsck from util-linux-ng 2.17.2
e2fsck 1.41.11 (14-Mar-2010)
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda5

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>

demo@demo-laptop:~$ sudo e2fsck -b 8193 /dev/sda5
e2fsck 1.41.11 (14-Mar-2010)
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda5

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
```

Kindly help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Belongs to http://askubuntu.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful. Check whether the partition is an extended partition or a swap partition. Try `sudo fdisk -l`, which should tell you about all the partitions on the system.

Comment: Its an extended partition. Its visible in the partition table(/dev/sda5)                                                       demo@demo-laptop:~$ sudo fdisk -l       
/dev/sda1               1        3221    25867979    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda2            3221       19456   130412033    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5            6375       12748    51199155   83  Linux
/dev/sda6   *       12749       19456    53881978+  83  Linux
/dev/sda7            3221        6238    24237056   83  Linux
/dev/sda8            6238        6374     1092608   82  Linux swap /